# Java - Prevent PrintWriter to overwrite the entire file everytime

Tags: java, csv, printwriter

I have a simulation program that needs to write certain results to a csv file very frequently during execution. I have found that there is something wrong with the printwriter which dramatically slows down running my program, as the output file is getting larger in size (near to 1 million rows). I doublt it's overwriting the entire file each time from the beginning, wheras I just need to append a single line at the bottom each time when it's being called. below is the code related to the writing fuctions.

one of the writing fuctions:

```
    public void printHubSummary(Hub hub, String filePath) {
        
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();   
            
            String h = hub.getHub_code();
            String date = Integer.toString(hub.getGs().getDate());
            String time = hub.getGs().getHHMMFromMinute(hub.getGs().getClock());
            String wgt = Double.toString(hub.getIb_wgt());

                    
            sb.append(h+","+date+","+time+","+wgt);
//          System.out.println("truck print line: " + sb);
            FileWriter.writeFile(sb.toString(),filePath);
        }
        
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something wrong when outputing truck summary file!");
            e.printStackTrace();        
        }
    }
```

the file writer code: (should be where the problem is!)

```
    public static boolean writeFile(String newStr, String filename) throws IOException {
    boolean flag = false;
    String filein = newStr + "\r\n";
    String temp = "";

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(filename);
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

        for (int j = 1; (temp = br.readLine()) != null; j++) {
            buf = buf.append(temp);
            buf = buf.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        if (buf.length() > 0 && buf.charAt(0) == '\uFEFF') {
            buf.deleteCharAt(0);
        }
        buf.append(filein);

        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] unicode = {(byte)0xEF, (byte)0xBB, (byte)0xBF};
        fos.write(unicode);
        pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
        
        pw.write(buf.toString().toCharArray());
        pw.flush();
        flag = true;
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        throw e1;
    } finally {
        if (pw != null) {
            pw.close();
        }
        if (fos != null) {
            fos.close();
        }
        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
        if (isr != null) {
            isr.close();
        }
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

An update on code modification. I have freezed the operations of repeatitively overwrting the entire file. It appears to solve the problem, but writing for sometime it's slowed down as well. Is it the best arrangement for wrting very large file? what other modifications can be done to make it even more efficient?

```
public static boolean writeFile1(String newStr, String filename) throws IOException {
        boolean flag = false;
        String filein = newStr + "\r\n";
        String temp = "";

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        InputStreamReader isr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(filename);
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
            br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

//          for (int j = 1; (temp = br.readLine()) != null; j++) {
//              buf = buf.append(temp);
//              buf = buf.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
//          }
//          if (buf.length() > 0 && buf.charAt(0) == '\uFEFF') {
//              buf.deleteCharAt(0);
//          }
            buf.append(filein);

            fos = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
            byte[] unicode = {(byte)0xEF, (byte)0xBB, (byte)0xBF};
            fos.write(unicode);
            pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
            
            pw.write(buf.toString().toCharArray());
            pw.flush();
            flag = true;
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            throw e1;
        } finally {
            if (pw != null) {
                pw.close();
            }
            if (fos != null) {
                fos.close();
            }
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
            if (isr != null) {
                isr.close();
            }
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you reading in the entire file each time you write a new line to it? Then writing the entire file out again?

Comment: Just keep your one printWriter alive, do not create a new one anytime you call the function, use the one over and over again. Alternatively open the file in "append" mode and only write the new line.

Comment: I doubt it is, which could be the cause.

Comment: @luk2302 could you suggest the concrete modification on codes?

Comment: I'd suggest reading some docs. I don't see any reason to read the entire file into a string then write it back out again. I'd be wary of keeping the file open if this is a long-running operation as the possibility of losing data increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a second argument to the `FileOutputStream` constructor to specify whether or not to use append mode, which will add to the end of the file rather than overwriting it.

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```

Alternatively, you could create a single static PrintWriter in append mode, which will probably be faster as it reduces garbage collection.

Comment: it becomes much more slower by adding the "true", why?

Comment: @Jack I'm not sure about that. Does it work though?

Comment: it becomes even greatly slower. almost stuck!

Comment: @Jack After making this modification, do not read the entire file and write it back, as that is no longer necessary. Only write parts you actually need to add, i.e. just write `filein`.

Comment: please see my update in edit. Now it's running in much faster speed. But is it the best arrangement for wrting very large file? what other modifications can be done to make it even more efficient?

Comment: That should be efficient enough. Alternatively, you could create a single static PrintWriter in append mode, which could be faster as it reduces garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Files / Path / Java NIO2 which is richer: the code below would need Java 7 at least.

```
Path path = Paths.get(filename);
try (BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(
      path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.APPEND, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
  bw.append(filein);
  bw.newLine();
}
```

Your cue here is the `StandardOpenOption`.

You will probably have to do some additional code **before** to write the Unicode part (and fix the `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`):

```
if (Files.notExists(path)) {
  Files.write(path, new byte[] {(byte)0xEF, (byte)0xBB, (byte)0xBF});
}
```

Also, try to not use `StringBuffer` in a local method, use `StringBuilder`: you don't need synchronisation most of the time.